# Python moving a text file of numbers into lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

**I have a text file of numbers:**

```
20 30 10
20 20 30
10 30 40
```

And need each column to be put into three separate lists through the standard Python file reading like so.

```
List1 =[20,20,10] and so on
```

I’ve been trying different things but nothing has worked. I can’t use NumPy arrays unfortunately though.

EDIT: forgot to mention that the first two columns are separated by tabs if that helps. It was causing me trouble

Comment: This isn't clear. Are you trying to create three independent lists or are you trying to create a list of lists? In any event -- this sounds like homework. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You won't benefit from having others do your homework for you.

Comment: _"I’ve been trying different things but nothing has worked."_ - Your question should be about one of those things you tried. What did not work? Show what you have tried.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this

```
20 30 10
20 20 30
10 30 40
```

Just from a text file this code will do the job:

```
file = open('file.txt')
lines = file.read().splitlines()

#you get ['20 30 10', '20 20 30', '10 30 40']

number_of_cols = len(lines[0].split(' '))
number_of_rows = len(lines)

ar = []
for l in lines:
    ar.append(l.split(' '))

#you get [['20', '30', '10'], ['20', '20', '30'], ['10', '30', '40']]

for c in range(0, number_of_cols):
    globals()['column{}'.format(c+1)] = []
    for r in range(0, number_of_rows):
        globals()['column{}'.format(c+1)].append(ar[r][c])

print(column1)
print(column2)
print(column3)
```

You will get

```
['20', '20', '10']
['30', '20', '30']
['10', '30', '40']
```

Also code should work if you add more columns or rows.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
all_data = []

with open(<filename>, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        all_data.extend(line.rstrip().split('\t'))

list1 = all_data[::3]
list2 = all_data[1::3]
list3 = all_data[2::3]
```

You might also try converting your file into something that Pandas can pull from (e.g. excel or csv). Then, just read and grab columns.